# Lua pattern similar to regex positive lookahead?

Tags: regex, lua, lua-patterns

I have a string which can contain any number of the delimiter `§\n`. I would like to remove all delimiters from a string, except the last occurrence which should be left as-is. The last delimiter can be in three states: `\n`, `§\n` or `§§\n`. There will never be any characters after the last variable delimiter.

Here are 3 examples with the different state delimiters:

```
abc§\ndef§\nghi\n
abc§\ndef§\nghi§\n
abc§\ndef§\nghi§§\n
```

I would like to remove all delimiters *except* the last occurrence.

So the result of gsub for the three examples above should be:

```
abcdefghi\n
abcdefghi§\n
abcdefghi§§\n
```

Using regular expressions, one could use `§\\n(?=.)`, which matches properly for all three cases using positive lookahead, as there will never be any characters after the last variable delimiter.

I know I could check if the string has the delimiter at the end, and then after a substitution using the Lua pattern `§\n` I could add the delimiter back onto the string. That is however a very inelegant solution to a problem which should be possible to solve using a Lua pattern alone.

So how could this be done using a Lua pattern?

Comment: what is the unicode / name of the character you use as a delimiter?

Comment: The string "§\n" (section sign followed by a line feed) is the delimiter. Unicode: U+00A7 followed by U+000A.

Comment: I would probably just capture the delimiter at the end first, gsub them all out, and then append the captured delimiter back on the end.

Comment: I am currently doing that in my production code but I would like to only use gsub without appending the delimiter afterwards. It's not a *bad* solution but I'm sure it could be done better with gsub alone, which is why I asked this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str:gsub( '§\\n(.)', '%1' )` should do what you want. This deletes the delimiter given that it is followed by another character, putting this character back into to string.

Test code

```
local str = {
    'abc§\\ndef§\\nghi\\n',
    'abc§\\ndef§\\nghi§\\n',
    'abc§\\ndef§\\nghi§§\\n',
}

for i = 1, #str do
    print( ( str[ i ]:gsub( '§\\n(.)', '%1' ) ) )
end
```

yields

```
abcdefghi\n
abcdefghi§\n
abcdefghi§§\n
```

Comment: I actually did mean a line feed "\n" or (HEX) 0x0A but I can work with this.

Comment: Yes, I did suspect that and tested the above with `\n` instead of `\\n` as well...

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: This answer doesn't work specifically for lua, but if you have a similar problem and are not constrained to lua you might be able to use it.

So if I understand correctly, you want a regex replace to make the first example look like the second.  This:

`/(.*?)§\\n(?=.*\\n)/g`

will eliminate the non-last delimiters when replaced with

`$1`

in PCRE, at least. I'm not sure what flavor Lua follows, but you can see the example [in action here.](http://regex101.com/r/gP7bG3)

REGEX:
`/(.*?)§\\n(?=.*\\n)/g`

TEST STRING:
`abc§\ndef§\nghi\n
abc§\ndef§\nghi§\n
abc§\ndef§\nghi§§\n`

SUBSTITUTION:
`$1`

RESULT:
`abcdefghi\n
abcdefghi§\n
abcdefghi§§\n`

Comment: Ah, I see. I've never used lua before. I'll keep the answer here in case it does come in useful for someone else, though.